# Verifying if an app icon is set before sending a build to iTunesConnect using Fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I am having this in my Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :qa do

    increment_build_number
    build_app(
        clean: true
    )
    verify_build(
       bundle_identifier: "xxx.com.fastlane-integration"
   )
   upload_to_testflight(skip_submission: true)
  end
end
```

The thing is, if I don't set an app icon, build will still uploaded, then I will get error message that app icon is missing, and sending of a build will fail.

What I want is that, build is not triggered at all if there is no app icon set. Is this possible?

Comment: You could write a unit test to check if an asset exists, then run tests as a step in your pipeline before you run the build.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano Oh... So there is nothing in Fastlane that actually do this check?

Comment: there is this library here https://github.com/fastlane-community/fastlane-plugin-appicon which will fail as a build step if it can't generate an icon for you however that isn't so much what you've explicitly asked for. Out of the box fastlane doesn't do this.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano Ok Brandon. Thank you... You can make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this library here [github.com/fastlane-community/fastlane-plugin-appicon](https://github.com/fastlane-community/fastlane-plugin-appicon) which will fail as a build step if it can't generate an icon for you however that isn't so much what you've explicitly asked for. Out of the box fastlane doesn't do this